# OracleBulkCopy WriteToServer method not working for large records

Tags: odp.net, oracle19c

We have recently migrated Oracle 12c to Oracle 19c, where for ODP.Net we have used DDTek.Oracle but for migrated code we are using Oracle.DataAccess dll.

We have requirement to load file data into database, to achieve this we have implemented .Net code by using Oracle.DataAccess.Client BulkCopy, WriteToServer() functionality where we have Oracle19c as database, we have one file of 2.6 million records which is throwing error

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. this is often an indication that memory is corrupt

The same code is working fine for Oracle 12c with DDTek.Oracle dll for 2.6 million records, but not in migrated oracle version.

Comment: Please avoid using Indian words here. People elsewhere aren't going to understand what are "lakh records".

Comment: use managed provider 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/OracleBulkCopyClass.html#GUID-3993FDA1-2807-4F66-A078-9A2C7091E2ED